# Smarty wildcard selector for string

Tags: php, smarty

Quick and simple, I have an app that works entirely on Smarty; basically I have {if} statement to determine what URI is user currently viewing so I can decide what to serve, it looks like:

```
    $GLOBALS.user_page_uri == '/private-messages/contacts/'
```

That opens all contacts, and when you click on some you open /private-messages/contacts/ID
So I need some kind of wildcard that will go at the end of code above so it only looks for "/private-messages/contacts/" and ignores everything after, I tried "*" and "%" but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few hours of knocking around (I'm not an PHP/smarty expert) I managed to find solution, instead of $string = 'something' I used preg_match()

So I got it working by giving:

```
preg_match("/\/private-messages\/contacts.*/s", $GLOBALS.user_page_uri);
```

Hope someone finds this helpful, I know it saved me a lot.